# Bluemix crashes everytime with "out of memory"...even at 4GB

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I'm running a fairly simply NodeJS app that crashes within about 1 minute on Bluemix with 'out of memory' errors.  This app runs locally and never exceeds 55 MB.  I have allocated 4GB to my Bluemix instance yet it still crashes. Is there a special memory allocation setting I need for NodeJS on Bluemix.  About ready to dump Bluemix and go back to Pivotal.  I haven't had any of these issues there.  As there both based on Cloud Foundry, I have to assume with is a Bluemix instability issue.

Answer (score 1):

OK..seemed to have tracked down the issue. Turned out to be two issues:

1) Seems to be a UI design bug.  I was updating my memory to 4GB then pressing 'Restart' instead of clicking "Save" first.  A better user experience would be to ask the user if they wanted to save their memory changes rather than simply restarting the app with the old memory setting.

2) Ensure you update the value of your memory parameter in your manifest.yml file as well.  Otherwise even if you update your memory on the server, it will be reverted back to whatever's in your manifest.yml next time you push your app live.

Short of it, be sure to refresh your page after updating your memory and restarting the app to ensure your memory was increased properly.  Also look at the memory usage of your app in the console window after you've pushed it live.

Comment: The behavior you mention in #1 is already present in the Bluemix UI. Perhaps it was just added--not sure.